# Создание метода, типа array.length

Tags: java, ооп

По условию задачи необходимо, чтобы возвращался массив в переменную через точку оператор таким образом `int[] x = SequenceSum.sumOfN()`. Где `SequenceSum` это `int`, а `sumOfN` - метод, который выполняется с числом `SequenceSum`. Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Comment: Возможно, в процессе постановке задачи Java как-то подменила C#. В последнем это давно [возможно](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) (не уверен насчет примитивов, правда)

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите получить? Зачем вам такое реализовывать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот есть какое-то расширение языка, где подобное возможно: https://projectlombok.org/index.html

Но в чистой Java так сделать нельзя.

Comment: Блин, я тогда ничего не понимаю. А как тогда написан метод получения длины массива в Java?

Comment: Массивы реализованы на стороне JVM.

Answer (score -1):

Создаешь класс `SequenceSum` у которого в конструктор передаешь число, в этом классе реализуешь  метод `sumOfN` который будет возвращать массив интов.
Пример:

```
public class SequenceSum{
 private int x;
 private int[] y;

 public SequenceSum(int x){
  this.x = x;
 }

 public int[] sumOfN(){
  y = new int[x];
  for(int i = 0;i<x;i++)
   y[i] = i+1;
  return y;
 }

}
```

Вызываем так:

```
 int[] x = SequenceSum(10).sumOfN();
```

P.S какая у вас логика я не знаю, но принцип примерно такой.

Comment: Узнать длину массива можно так int x = array.length; Как можно в моем случае реализовать такую структуру? Меня бы и простой способ устроил, но по задаче именно так нужно.

Comment: Создать свой класс с методом `length`.

Comment: И еще `SequenceSum` не может иметь тип `int`. `int` это примитивный тип, а `SequenceSum` это ссылочный